# Regex in C# only returns the first match

Tags: regex

I am trying to just simply disassemble a comma-separated string using the Regex below:

```
[^,]+
```

However, I get a different result from this Regex in C# than other engines such as online Regex compilers.

C# for some reason only detects the first element in the string and that's all.

[Sample comma-separated string compiled online.](http://regex101.com/r/hQ5qQ0/1)

The code I use in C# which returns: `Foo`

```
        var longString = "Foo, \nBar, \nBaz, \nQux"
        var match = Regex.Match(longString, @"[^,]+");
        var cutStrings = new List<string>();
        if (match.Success)
        {
            foreach (var capture in match.Captures)
            {
                cutStrings.Add(capture.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is pretty normal for a "match" function. Python does the same thing, and it's generally more consistent with formal treatment of regular expressions. I think your expectations are being falsely set by "online compilers."

Comment: @jpmc26 would you be able to look at the sample I put in for the online compiler and point out the false settings, if any? thanks

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding. I don't mean you have false settings. I mean that the online compilers are making you expect things you shouldn't expect.

Comment: @jpmc26 in this case it was a simple mistake as Sina pointed out. However my understanding from what you said is that, the online compilers don't necessarily behave correctly and maybe not to be trusted 100%. right?

Comment: It's not that they behave incorrectly or aren't trustworthy. It's that because they're *graphical*, they do things like find all matches by default because it's more useful when you're staring at the string. On the other hand, most programming languages will find the first match and return it, unless you call a function specially designed to find all the matches. They do that because since you're writing code, you need the ability to choose between which one you want. The point is, don't expect a code library to behave the same as a graphical tool by default or in all cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Regex.Match` returns the first match. Try `Regex.Matches` to give you the collection of results.

Comment: That's beautiful. Never knew there is one like that. I always used `Regex.Match` and later on refered to my name group like, `match.Group["x"].Captures` and since this case was very simple I didn't name my group and BAM! now I know. Cheers